# VB.NET Connection In ALL forms

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

How to Connection all my forms using only one time setup database?

what's happening to me now is every form i made i always put my database connection

Answer (score 1):

Create a module and make a shared function that you can call it from anywhere.

**to get data to your dataset call it from anywhere within your project**

```
        Try
            Dim dsEmployee As New DataSet()
            dsEmployee = ExecuteDataSet("select * from tblEmployee")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Getting error while getting dataset. " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Data Base", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

**for insert records to your database**

```
ExecuteNonQuery("insert into tblEmployee(Emp_ID,Emp_Code,Emp_Name,Emp_Mobile)values(1,'EMP1','Anand','+91 98000000')")
```

**Create a module and make all required function and put your database connection string to `MyConnection` string vaiable**

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module dbConnect
Dim MyConnection As String = "data source=MyPc;Initial Catalog=TestDb;User ID=sa;Password=12345;"

    Public Function ExecuteDataSet(ByVal _Query As String) As DataSet
        Dim dsReturn As New DataSet
        Try
            Dim conn As String = MyConnection
            Using con = New SqlConnection(conn)
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(_Query)
                cmd1.Connection = con
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
                dsReturn = New DataSet
                da.Fill(dsReturn)
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error While Getting DataSet :" + vbNewLine + ex.Message.ToString(), " ERROR ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        Return dsReturn
    End Function

    Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal _Query As String) As Integer
        Dim res As Integer = 0
        Try
            Dim conn As String = MyConnection
            Using con = New SqlConnection(conn)
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand()
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                cmd.CommandText = _Query
                cmd.Connection = con
                res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error While Inserting Records :" + vbNewLine + ex.Message.ToString(), " ERROR ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        Return res
    End Function

End Module
```